# A first order nonlinear PDE system: Do solutions exist?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Consider the following system of first order nonlinear partial differential equations.

$0 = B_y (\frac{\partial B_y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial B_x}{\partial y}) + B_z (\frac{\partial B_z}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial B_x}{\partial z})$

$0 = B_x (\frac{\partial B_x}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial B_y}{\partial x}) + B_z (\frac{\partial B_z}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial B_y}{\partial z})$

$0 = B_x (\frac{\partial B_x}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial x}) + B_y (\frac{\partial B_y}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial y})$

$0 = \frac{\partial B_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial B_y}{\partial y} +  \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial z}$

where $B_x$, $B_y$ and $B_z$ vanish at infinity. Do nontrivial solutions for $B_x$, $B_y$ and $B_z$ exist? Also I think that of the first three equations we can toss out one since it can be derived from the other two.

Comment: Using vector calculus identities, this system can be rewritten as $B \times (\nabla \times B) = 0$ and $\nabla \cdot B = 0$, which reminds me a lot of 
the equations for a magnetic field.

Comment: The equations result from setting the Lorentz force density to zero everywhere.

Comment: I think you are asking for a solution with $\nabla\times B\ne0$, because in the contrary it has solutions  with $B\ne0$ (the free space ones).

Comment: Thank you, Rafa. That is indeed the case. I am looking for solutions such that $\nabla \times {\bf B} \ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

There are nontrivial solutions with $\nabla\times B\neq 0$.  In the literature, $B$ is called a [Beltrami vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_vector_field). 
 This system arises in the equations of incompressible fluid mechanics, where $B$ there represents the velocity vector field of the fluid.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_flow) for examples of solutions.  Other examples are easily found using the Fourier or Laplace transforms, for example, or simply separation of variables.

Note that if $\nabla\times B\neq 0$, then boundary value problems are difficult to solve, since the corresponding solutions $B$ to Helmholtz's equation $\nabla^2B=-\lambda^2 B$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_vector_field)) must also satisfy $\nabla\times B=\lambda B$.  However, in the case $\nabla\times B=0$, we get Laplace's equation $\nabla^2B=0$, which is known as [potential flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow).

Comment: Thanks @user254433. I will check it out. Last week i realized this was a problem of finding eigenvectors for the curl operator.